# u nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30' when installing on RTX 3080 system

Tags: ffmpeg

Im follwing this guide https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/ to install ffmpeg on Ubunut "Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"

with NVIDIA-SMI 455.38

I'm using Image: nvidia/cuda:11.1-devel-ubuntu16.04 and it has cuda-toolkit installed.

running ./configure --enable-nonfree  --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64

generates this

ERROR: failed checking for nvcc.

log file shows this

nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -O2 -m64 -ptx -c -o /tmp/ffconf.WzHPgzvz/test.o /tmp/ffconf.WzHPgzvz/test.cu
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'
ERROR: failed checking for nvcc.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CgRhCZ9T29/

Comment: I edited the file  /ffmpeg/configure and changed compute_30 to 86 as this is RTX3080's. but now it give this error

Comment: Cannot load libnvidia-encode.so.1
but is only in old drivers nvidia-304 to 384

Comment: I had the same error. For me, changing `compute_30` to `compute_35` and `sm_30` to `sm_35` inside the `ffmpeg/configure` worked.

Comment: You may pass flag `--nvccflags='-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -O2'` to configure